# BigQuery - How to query custom channel grouping from Google Analytics 4

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I'm trying to query in BQ the custom channel grouping that my company already defined in GA4.
Any tips on how to achieve that? I found a lot of posts on [creating custom channels](https://www.ga4bigquery.com/tutorial-how-to-create-your-own-custom-channel-grouping/) inside BQ but not how to query them from GA4 if they have already been created previously.

In GA4 I can use the custom channels properly so there is no issue with the settings. However I'm not sure where is it in BQ. It's not part of the list of events apparently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Channel Groups are rule_based definitions of traffic sources , Default and Custom Channel groups are not built-in in Big query reports but you can make them by filtering *traffic_source.source* and *traffic_source.medium* column values. to know the rules and use them for writing your query check this [google guideline](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9756891?hl=en) or check channel group section in the GA4 admin tab.

Comment: thanks, I think I understand the logic better. traffic_source is at user level, not session level right?

Comment: NO , it's on the session level. To find first user-level source and medium you can check the traffic_source when the ga_session_number = 1

Comment: I see, thanks a lot for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

correctly configure  dimensions within GA4 structure of your GA4 data go for select based on traffic_source  probing

Comment: The dimensions should be properly configured. It's working find in GA4 so there is no issue with the configuration. However, I'm not sure where to find the Custom channel grouping in BQ, I did not find it in the list of events.